# How do I verify Traefik configurations

Tags: traefik

I am absolutely in love with Traefik. As a beginner, however, I miss Nginx style `nginx -t` to verify the configuration files.

I am running traefik in a docker container and whenever I update my configuration files (the *.toml ones), is there a way I can check if there were errors or not?

Comment: At the moment, this functionality doesn't look like it's supported. I've checked the docs and the API but nothing mentions validating the `toml` config.

Comment: @steadweb thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

As @steadweb mentioned, there does not seem to be a functionality to validate .toml-configs for traefik, but `docker logs <traefik-container>` should give you at least some insight whether the startup went as it was supposed to or not.